# Going through specified items in a page using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

I'm running into some trouble trying to enter and analyze several items within a page.

I have a certain page which contains items in it, the code looks something like this

```
class Spider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'spider'
maxId = 20
allowed_domain = ['www.domain.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.startDomain.com']
```

In the start url, i have some items that all follow, in XPath, the following path (within the startDomain):

```
def start_requests(self):

    for i in range(self.maxId):
        yield Request('//*[@id="result_{0}"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2'.format(i) , callback = self.parse_item)
```

I'd like to find a way to access each one of these links (the ones tied to result{number}) and then scrape the contents of that certain item.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific, which website are you trying to crawl? What are the items you are trying to get?

Comment: Already fixed it!. My problem was that i was not using the link extractor the right way, thanks anyway